# Integrating volume integral with respect to a single variable

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I came across the following integral:
$\int f\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dr$ where dr is the volume element and the integral is over all space.

The integral was integrated by parts with respect to x to obtain [assuming g vanishes at infinity]:
$\int -g\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dr$.

I am unable to understand how one can integrate with respect to x only.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: and neither am I. Aren't we integrating w.r.t $r$, instead?

Comment: No, the text says integrating by parts wrt x

Comment: Words like integrating by parts and product rule are often used synonymously with each other. And possibly if the integrand they left out was a surface term that vanishes possibly infinitely far away.